# IOS Uploading App to appStore errors

Tags: ios

I am trying to upload an iOS application to the App Store on Xcode, but for some reason after it passes validation the application is stuck on "Your Application is Being Uploaded". and when i have tried to  edit schema -> build configuration change it to release then get the .app and compress it to upload it with application loader it gives me an error when i run the code in release "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." (although its working on debug perfectly) iam sure that code signing working 100% i have put the developer profile under debug and distribution profile under release 
NOTE:my project contains two projects and i have read to change the dependent project to skip install YES and i have done this to avoid errors, any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **Archive** the app before release, and make sure the Archive configuration is set to **Release**.

Comment: when i change the build configuration to release and then archive and then run the app same error appear ,